# How to go back three steps from the path recieved by GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to go back three steps from the current Executing assembly so that I get the name of the folder present there. My requirement is not fulfilled  by using ..\..\..\.

so suggest.

Thanks

Comment: please show some code and explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: _"go back three steps"_ What should that mean? What kind of _steps_?

Comment: like my Exe is placed in the following path C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\bin\debug\exe.    Now I got the path of the exe by using string CurrentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);       I need to fetch either the base folder name i.e folder3 or to go there by backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Get path of executing assembly

```
Uri path = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase));
```

Then you can do youre stuff (possible look at segment property) or add ......\ after the path

```
// get path and transform into FileInfo
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path.LocalPath);
// now you can go up with property Parent
var directory = fi.Directory.Parent;
```